# Upper bound of summation $\sum_{m < \frac{1}{2}X} \frac{|a(m_1m_2^2)|}{m_1m_2^2} \log\frac{X}{m}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

I am studying the paper M. Ram Murty, V. Kumar Murty: Mean values of derivatives of modular $L$-series, Ann. of Math. (2) 133 (1991), no. 3, 447-475.

Let $L(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(m)}{m^s}$ be the $L$-function of a modular elliptic curve with conductor $N$. We decompose $m=m_1m_2$ such that $m_1$ is the product of prime factors (with multiplicity) of $m$ which divide $N$ (i.e., $m_2=n/m_1$ is coprime to $N$). We only consider $m$ such that $m_2$ is square, so we write $m=m_1m_2^2$ instead of $m=m_1m_2$.

In p.457, the authors state that

$$Y\sum_{m < \frac{1}{2}X}\frac{|a(m_1m_2^2)|}{m_1m_2^2} \log\frac{X}{m}+Y\sum_{m>\frac{1}{2}X}\frac{|a(m_1m_2^2)|}{m_1m_2^2}\tau(m)\mathrm{exp}(-m/X) \ll Y(\log X)^2.$$

However, I don't know why this estimate holds.

Comment: I'm not sure the second part is stated correctly in the paper. I think it should be $\tau(m_1m_2)$ instead of $\tau(m)$ (from the preceding calculation), and this makes a difference in the order of the pole, thus power of log you get...

Comment: MyNinthAccont // you get what...?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question so as to refer to the Murty brothers as who they are, two distinct persons.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Iwaniec's version in any case. https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/item/?id=JTNB_1990__2_2_365_0

Comment: Thank you for everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof for non CM elliptic curves. In this case, the Dirichlet series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a(n^2)^2}{n^{2+s}}$$
is holomorphic in the closed half-plane $\Re(s)\geq 1$ with a simple pole at $s=1$. This follows, for example, from Lemma 3 in Moreno-Shahidi: The fourth moment of Ramanujan $\tau$-function (1983) combined with Lemma 2.2 in Lü: Sums of absolute values of cusp form coefficients and their application (2014). Of course Lü's paper is more recent than that of Murty and Murty, but the quoted lemma is rather standard. By the Wiener-Ikehara theorem, we conclude the asymptotic formula (for some $c>0$)
$$\sum_{n\leq T}\frac{a(n^2)^2}{n^2}\sim c T\qquad\text{as}\qquad T\to\infty.$$
In particular,
$$\sum_{T/2<n\leq T}|a(n^2)|\leq T\sum_{T/2<n\leq T}\frac{|a(n^2)|}{n}\leq T\sum_{T/2<n\leq T}\left(1+\frac{a(n^2)^2}{n^2}\right)\ll_N T^2.$$
From here the bound follows easily by a dyadic decomposition in $m_2$, upon noting that
$$\sum_{m_1\mid(2N)^\infty}\frac{|a(m_1)|\tau(m_1)}{m_1}\ll_N 1.$$

**P.S.** See my comments below for additional details.

Comment: Why is $a(p)\ll p^{2/5}$? Am I being dumb with normalizations here? I thought $a(p)\ll p^{1/2}$, and indeed inserting that seems to give the extra log. But I’m afraid I’m probably confused by normalizations...

Comment: Normalizations are terrifying! The physicists are ahead of us in setting $2=-1=\pi=i=G=c=\cdots=1$ :).

Comment: @alpoge: I updated my post, have a look.

Comment: So one doesn't need to have a Rankin-like log-saving estimate on $\sum_n |a(n^2)|$, but only the "trivial" bound from Cauchy and $\sum_n |a(n^2)|^2$ (however weighted by $1/n$ as your normalization prefers).

Comment: I can't yet understand your arguments. Why the dyadic decomposition implies our estimate? Could you let me know the details?

Comment: @LWW: For the first part of the sum, it suffices to show $\sum_{m < X/2}\frac{|a(m_1m_2^2)|}{m_1m_2^2}\ll\log X$. Let us relax the condition $m<X/2$ to $m_2<X/2$, i.e., $m_1$ is no longer bounded. Then we can factor our out $\sum_{m_1}|a(m_1)|/m_1$ which is $\ll_N 1$ as $m_1$ is supported on the prime factors of $2N$. So it remains to show that $\sum_{m_2 < X/2}\frac{|a(m_2^2)|}{m_2^2}\ll_N\log X$. This follows from my third display. Indeed, the contribution of every dyadic range $T/2<m_2\leq T$ is $\ll_N$, and we can cover the whole range by $\ll\log X$ dyadic ranges.

Comment: @LWW: The second part of the sum can be handled similarly, just decompose to dyadic ranges and see what happens.

Comment: @GH from MO: Thank you. Now I understand what happens in the first sum. However, I couldn't catch what happens in the second sum. In the second sum, 'dyadic decomposition' you say means $(1/2)X<m_2<X$, $X<m_2<2X$,...right?

Comment: In the second sum, the dyadic decomposition implies the sum is bounded by $\sum_{1/2X < m_2 \leq X}4\tau(m_2)\exp(-1/2) + \sum_{X < m_2 \leq 2X}\tau(m_2)\exp(-1)+\sum_{2X<m_2 \leq 4X}\frac{1}{2}\tau(m_2)\exp(-2)+\cdots$. This is bounded by $\log(X)$? Is this right what you said?

Comment: @LVW: No. Let us restrict to $m_1=1$ for simplicity. Then the first dyadic range is $\sum_{X/2<m_2\leq X}\frac{|a(m_2^2)|\tau(m_2)}{m_2^2}$. By Cauchy-Schwartz, this is at most the geometric mean of $\sum_{X/2<m_2\leq X}\frac{a(m_2^2)^2}{m_2^3}$ and $\sum_{X/2<m_2\leq X}\frac{\tau(m_2)^2}{m_2}$. The first sum is $\ll_N$ by my second display, while the second sum is $\ll(\log X)^4$ by standard analytic number theory. So the geometric mean is $\ll(\log X)^2$. The other dyadic ranges are much smaller because of the decaying exponential factor, so the total sum is still $\ll(\log X)^2$.

Comment: @GH from MO: I think you say 'standard analytic number theory' means $\sum_{n \leq X} \tau(n)^k \sim X(\log X)^{2^k-1}$. That's okay. However, you said 'because of the decaying exponential factor, so the total sum is still $\ll (\log X)^2$' looks unrigorous. Really? And I'll accept your answer officially. Thank you for your kind. Your answer and comments are very helpful for me!

Comment: One more, Could you give me just some hint or references for CM case?

Comment: @LWW: 1. I meant the bound $\sum_{n\leq X}\tau(n)^k/n<(1+\log X)^{2^k}$, which is standard. 2. The $\ll(\log X)^2$ becomes rigorous once you fill in the details. The exponential factor makes the dyadic contributions decay super fast. Just write it out, and you will see. 3. For a CM elliptic curve, the L-function agrees with a Hecke L-function of a quadratic number field. So the $a(n)$'s are more explicit, as in (8.34) of Iwaniec: Topics in classical automorphic forms, and simpler tools can be brought on the problem. Hope this helps! Unfortunately, I don't have more time to think about this.

Comment: @GH from MO: Okay. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

As this hasn't attracted an answer yet, I will make my comments.

IMO the authors simply claimed this, and if I am guessing their intended method correctly, it doesn't actually work as easily as presumed.

Let's ignore the $m_1$, drop the $Y$, and use $\log (X/m)\le\log X$ in the first sum.

Then we want to show (here $n$ is $m_2$)
$$\sum_{n<X} {|a(n^2)|\over n^2}\ll \log X.$$
My guess is that the authors basically assumed that this was similar to $\sum_n |a(n)|^2/n^2$, which is indeed the classical Rankin convolution. The routine argument says (e.g.)
$$\sum_{n\le X}{|a(n)|^2\over n^2}
\ll\sum_n{|a(n)|^2\over n^2}e^{-n/X}
=\int X^s\Gamma(s)L(f\otimes f,s+2){ds\over 2\pi i}$$
and the self-convolution $L$-function has a simple pole at $s=2$, thus a double pole for the integrand at $s=0$, giving $\ll\log X$. (You can include the $m_1$ as a finite Euler product that is nice somewhat to the left of $\sigma=0$.) A similar argument presumably works with $\tau(n)$ included (though not $\tau(n^2)$ if I am correct), as that just appends another $\log X$.

But the situation with $|a(n^2)|$ is different. Again I can't know their thoughts, and the method I propose is (much) too complicated to go without comment. Here goes: note $a(n^2)$ gives (up to bad Euler factors and a tame $\zeta$-factor) the symmetric square coefficients (see middle of page 450). Then the $L^1$-norm of these symmetric square coefficients can be bounded, similar to the paper's Lemma 17 (Rankin's bound for $\sum_n |a(n)|$), with a savings of a power of log. (I'm not actually sure how much one needs holomorphy of the self-convolution of the symmetric square, or indeed whether the details of this were known at the time.) Then by partial summation one gets the desired bound. The second term is similar (again one can use smoothing as above), but again I think $\tau(m_2^2)$ is going to lose an extra logarithm.

Comment: One can note that this paper has an atypical history. The main result was essentially "known" to the cognoscenti, but only took on an imperative to be published when Kolyvagin used (a corollary of) it as a technical hypothesis in his work. That, plus the usual deference that Annals referees seem to have, likely meant the details were not under much scrutiny.

Comment: I don't think it is quite fair to describe this result as "essentially known."  Largely people were not working on such questions, and it was certainly significant  to recognize that such a result was needed and important to establish.  In 1991, the papers by Duke--Friedlander--Iwaniec were all yet to come.  I'm not sure how big the set of ``cognoscenti" would be for whom this was "essentially known."  I would guess that the number is at most five.

Comment: The principal reason this was "known" is that BFH announced (BAMS 5-page brief) that Kolyvagin's hypothesis followed by similar methods to their then in-press Annals paper (admittedly far afield from the Murtys' method). The date on the BAMS article is Dec 1988, the Murtys' paper was submitted late April 1989, the BFH Inventiones paper was May 1989. As you say, not many analytic number theorists worked on such questions (I recall a certain cultural bias in some circles against higher degree L-functions), but the averaging technique is somewhat known and IMO the difficulties mostly technical...

Comment: In fact, they themselves say "We stress that the naive approach to the proof the main theorem works after a few technical difficulties are surmounted"